# How can I prevent the pylint error which I'm receiving when attempting to lint python code?

Tags: pylint

How do I prevent pylint from firing error when linting my code ?

Comment: Did you install `pylint`? using `pip install pylint` or follow [this](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#note-for-windows-users)

Comment: When `pylint` or `pip` or both is installed and can be imported strictly though the python shell (REPL) that is not the same as accessing it though command (DOS), in other words, one has to install `pylint` or `pip` or both though command (DOS) as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by installing pylint and configuring pylint.